# Extension plans for formatting of trivial structs in C++ {fmt}?

Tags: c++, reflection, fmt

In my current project I need a custom very simple "serialized" representation of a couple of trivial data transfer object (DTO) structures. After first coming up with a custom made solution, that was a big PITA, I had the idea to use {fmt} for that.

So the last days I was playing around with formatting of custom types via extensions of the `fmt::formatter` template specialization mechanism. Therefore [this blog](https://wgml.pl/blog/formatting-user-defined-types-fmt.html) and [your docs](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types) were very helpful.

After a little bit of fiddling around, I came up with a pretty generic poc solution, that allows to format structures in multiple custom formats, that looks a little bit like the following:

```
struct Inner {
    double x;
    std::string y;
    int z;
};
struct Outer {
    int a;
    std::string b;
    Inner inner;
};

template<>
struct reflection<Outer> {
    /*definition of class name and field names has to be provided manually...*/
};

template<>
struct reflection<Inner> {
    /*definition of class name and field names has to provided manually...*/
};

/*
...
couple dozend lines of meta programming and fmt::formatter specializations.
...
*/

auto outer = Outer{.a=1,.b="hello",.inner={.x=3.12,.y=" ",.z=2}};

std::string simple = fmt::format("{:s}", outer); // :s means format as simple
assert(simple == "a|hello|3.12| |2");
assert(fmt::format("{:s;}", outer) == "a;hello;3.12; ;2");

std::string  extended = fmt::format("{:e}",outer); // :e means format as extended
assert(extended == "Outer{.a=1, .b=hello, .inner=Inner{.x=3.12, .y= , .z=2}}");
```

Obviously, there is no standard way to reflect about the fields and the name of a structure, so the reflection structure has to be provided either manually, or e.g. via macros-magic. But that is a different topic that I don't want to address here. - If we are lucky we get some minimal compile time reflection in c++23 \o/. Let's hope!

I put all this together in [this repo](https://github.com/martinitus/fmt-reflect).

The actual question:

Would formatting user defined types via a simple reflection API provided by {fmt} be something that you'd consider a possible future extension to {fmt}?
I imagine a scenario, where a couple of trivial formatting patterns are predefined, and the user only has to provide the reflection for his types.

With this, I can even see formatting expressions like `fmt::format("{:json,prety,tabwith=4}", outer)` on the horizon.

Also, maybe I'm just reinventing the wheel, so if there is something like this, based on {fmt} out there - tell me! :)

Anyway, thanks for providing your awesome tool to the community and congrats to making it into c++20!

Regards, Martin

Comment: What does DTO stand for?

Comment: Data Transfer Object, e.g. the representations of an internal/domain object with the sole purpose of integrating the internal/domain object with some serialization or database engine. Essentially glue code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would formatting user defined types via a simple reflection API provided by {fmt} be something that you'd consider a possible future extension to {fmt}?

Possibly but it will have to be an explicit opt-in, i.e. such types won't be formattable automatically in this way because normally you'd want a more high-level representation rather than a collection of fields. For example, you might want to format a point as `(x, y)` rather than `Point{.x=x, .y=y}`.

Comment: I absolutely agree. With the approach I currently experiment with, it requires both the appropriate includes (similar to `#include <fmt/range.h>`), and an explicit format specifier (i.e. `{:e}` or `{:foobar}`) to work. However, the later is only checked at runtime (i.e. `fmt::print("{}", outer)` would compile if the headers are present but fail at runtime) - I have to do further experiments with the compile time format strings to see if/how the explicit format string requirement can also be validated at compile time.

Comment: I guess I'll keep experimenting :) If I have something that I think is reasonably useful I'll come back and probably directly contact you via github!